# Getting "WinError 10054" When using urllib, trying to get info from a site. How to fix?

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to submit info to this site > https://cxkes.me/xbox/xuid

The info: `e = {'gamertag' : "Xi Fall iX"}`

Every time I try, I get `WinError 10054`. I can't seem to find a fix for this.

My Code:

```py
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import json

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
url = "https://cxkes.me/xbox/xuid"
e = {'gamertag' : "Xi Fall iX"}
f = {'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
     'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
     'accept-language': "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
     'cache-control': "max-age=0",
     'content-length': "76",
     'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     'cookie': "__cfduid=d2f371d250727dc4858ad1417bdbcfba71593253872; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjVcL2dHMGlYSGYwd3ZPVEpTRGlsMnFBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InA4bDJ6cEtNdzVOT3UxOXN4c2lcLzlKRTlYaVNvZjdpMkhqcmllSWN3eFdYTUxDVHd4Y2NiS0VqN3lDSll4UDhVMHM1TXY4cm9lNzlYVGE0dkRpVWVEZz09IiwibWFjIjoiYjdlNjU3ZDg3M2Y0MDBlZDY3OWE5YTdkMWUwNGRiZTVkMTc5OWE1MmY1MWQ5OTQ2ODEzNzlhNGFmZGNkZTA1YyJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjJTdlFhK0dacFZ4cFI5RFFxMHgySEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoia2F6UTJXVmNSTEt1M3lqekRuNVFqVE5ZQkpDang4WWhraEVuNm0zRmlVSjVTellNTDRUb1wvd1BaKzNmV2lISGNUQ0l6Z21jeFU3VlpiZzY0TzFCOHZ3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiIwODU3YzMxYzg2N2UzMjdkYjcxY2QyM2Y4OTVmMTY1YTcxZTAxZWI0YTExZDE0ZjFhYWI2NzRlODcyOTg3MjIzIn0%3D",
     'origin': "https://cxkes.me",
     'referer': "https://cxkes.me/xbox/xuid",
     'sec-fetch-dest': "document",
     'sec-fetch-mode': "navigate",
     'sec-fetch-site': "same-origin",
     'sec-fetch-user': "?1",
     'upgrade-insecure-requests': "1",
     'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(e)

data = json.dumps(data)
data = str(data)
data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, f)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   the_page = response.read()
print(the_page)
```

Comment: Is the problem solved? Have you had a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Having run the code, I get the following error

> [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

that could be caused by any of the followings:

- The network link between server and client may be temporarily going down.
- running out of system resources.
- sending malformed data.

I am not sure what you trying to achieve here entirely. But if your aim is to simply read the `XUID` of a gamer tag then use a web-automator like `Selenium` to retrieve that value.

Comment: It goes through a form but it has to be Decimal not HexaDecimal. which is selected by buttons